# Water drip trouble

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I do the Drip Water particle, I want it in my exact location and a normal speed, I know I could do this myself but I don't know how to, so can someone make the command? All I know is `/particle dripwater ~ ~ ~` and that's all because when I go on to the speed and count it just keeps saying how to do it, and I'm following it, but it's not working. I also tried not to do the speed and count thing but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> /summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~1 ~ {Particle:dripWater,Duration:9999,Age:0}

That should summon water drops above you, although it will disappear after a while but you can just raise duration number to make it last longer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /particle dripwater ~ ~1 ~ 0.5 1 0.5 1 10 10
```

into a command block.

If you want to change the speed just change the third to last number until you get it right(Smaller number= Slower Particle Movement)